# Magento 2 :Develop Multivendor Marketplace store in Magento

Tags: magento2, multi-vendor

How to create a multi-vendor marketplace in magento?

Comment: You can either go for Marketplace Basic Extension or Marketplace Platinum Package of cedcommerce, they have multi features as well as large number of magento 2 marketplace addon - https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/marketplace

Answer (score 1):

I am using Multi Vendor Marketplace extension check out [webkul marketplace extension](https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html), this extension support multi vendors, as come up with many more modules like split order by vendor, custom attribute for marketplace and massupload for vendors, which you have to purchase from Webkul.

For Free Marketplace you can see [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/izberg-marketplace-multi-vendor-multi-seller-drop-ship-solution-in-saas.html) or [here](https://www.knowband.com/magento-free-multi-vendor-marketplace-plugin)(its not tested)

Comment: ok thanks but i want to build by myself

Comment: so u have purchased the webkul extension?

Comment: yes i do. Developing a marketplace is not an easy task to do..

Comment: okay can u please tell me how they have managed the database or i mean where does seller details store